# MapView has a bad resolution comparing to generic Maps

Tags: android

I just received a HTC Desire to test on. I noticed, that a mapView residuing in a frame smaller than a whole screen is not as sharp as a generic maps application. Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should compile your application with API level 4 or higher and then set <supports-screens> in your AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
  <supports-screens
  android:largeScreens="true"
  android:normalScreens="true"
  android:smallScreens="true"
  android:anyDensity="true"
  />
```

As described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

This is because of two things:
1. Android 1.5 and lower doesn't support multiscreen configurations.
2. There are no high density devices running even 1.6 - all above 2.0 (AFAIK)

If you want support 1.5 devices (12% of market for now) you may compile two separate versions of your app.

Comment: I added <support-screens...> as shown above and compiled it as 1.6 and then even as 2.1. Both of them still had a map with bad resolution on my milestone. (I set the API Level in my Project settings, is that enough?)

Comment: Worked after setting "<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"/>"
 In project settings I only specify targetSdkVersion.

Answer (score 0):

Thats how it looks. I have the same problem. I used Google API 8 (Android 2.2) in the emulator with a resolution same as the DROID. My project settings although are API 4 (Android 1.6), because I also want to provide my app to older devices as well. (In this case I even should use 1.5)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you response. I think I am going to check out some Google's site to make some pressure maybe. The Maps on cutting-edge phones can't look like maps on iPhone < 3GS or we are going to take constant and rational beating from Apple lovers.