# MapView with maps that have the same resolution as Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

If you compare how the map looks in MapView and how it looks in Google Maps, you'll notice that in Google Maps the map is "bigger". The texts are bigger, roads wider etc. Can I achieve this in my MapView?

Comment: R u embadding ur map on realtive layout or linear layout????Relative layout will be good option

Answer (score 1):

**How to get maps in high resolution** (and maybe the rest of ur map layout issues) **is answered here:** [MapView has a bad resolution comparing to generic Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659851/mapview-has-a-bad-resolution-comparing-to-generic-maps/3700507#3700507)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have a different problem. This is how it looks: http://www.niola.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/device.png (notice the small fonts and narrow roads). This is how it should look: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_16aYP83FzVs/S6uyiX5evtI/AAAAAAAAAB0/CzajmK3-gYM/s1600/buzzlayer2.png.

Comment: Looks like u have a very high screen resolution on ur test device. Can u provide the same san francisco map map from ur device?

Comment: The problem is that Google Maps uses different map data, I hope they update MapView soon. Screenshot for San Francisco as it is displayed on my MapView: https://doc-10-cc-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/secure/e4lam5svm303jlijrsptqgj1qgmtpj73/upipl6i9d5d5undqt64gfti7qjnbqddf/1284616800000/07717629100330057660/07717629100330057660/0B3WcS6gOEtDkY2Y4ZmI5ZGEtZDNmZi00Y2NiLWI3ZmItZjQxZmYxY2M1M2Nk?nonce=9g266pk2ufrf6&user=07717629100330057660&hash=u91dkb7ot5po43skjf3h2ukhn6i31ivs

Comment: Ok, tested it with my device. Yes, the level of detail is different between gmaps app and the map view. The map view has more details. I like that more than the gmaps app by the way. I havent seen those differences in Germany yet. Maybe u can set the level of detail in ur app.

Comment: They now introduced the new map style in the nativ gmaps-app in germany as well. Same difference to mapview also. So I think, this question is answered now.